# распарсить с помощью jquery @Model.SelectList на стороне клиента

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mvc

Приложение на asp.net mvc5 jquery. Имеется представление, где ddl формируется динамически

```
<select><options></options></select>
```

Во вьюху приходт модель с `List<SelectListItem>`. Как спомощью джиквери получить массив с `<options value="item.Value">item.Text</options>`.Где item - это SelectListItem элемент списка.  Именно с помощью jquery.

Comment: в джиквери нет `item.Text`

Comment: блин, я совершенно не понимаю как тут печатать код - весь код из сообщения куда то делся нахрен

Comment: Игорь, ну что ты не понимаешь- item это из модели элемент SelectListItem

Comment: Если в модели уже есть список из `SelectListItem`, зачем Вам jQuery? Напишите во вью цикл по этому списку.

Comment: Игорь, так мне не надо. Я в джиквери разделю нужные мне Элементы в одну кучу ненужные в другую -тут все хитро. Но это неважно. Важно именно в джиквери мне это сделать. Можно и цикл не писать а хелпером воспользоваться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="mySelect"></select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var items = [
  @foreach(SelectListItem item in model.Items) {
    { value: "@item.Value", text: "@item.Text" },
  }
  ];
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $("#mySelect").append("<option value='"+items[i].value+"'>"+items[i].text+"</option>");
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Игорь, это почти сработало - но хлопотно это, сделал традиционно форычем в razor